# Powershell Script to collate all users within a number of local PC 'Remote Desktop Users'

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to create a powershell script to allow the above however keep coming unstuck with most of the threads only showing servers. Any help would be massively appreciated.

As above - hoping to output this xls/csv

```
# Function to get Remote Desktop Users for a computer
function Get-RemoteDesktopUsers {
    param (
        [string]$computerName
    )

    $remoteDesktopGroup = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users" -ComputerName $computerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($remoteDesktopGroup) {
        return $remoteDesktopGroup
    } else {
        return "No users found in Remote Desktop Users group on $computerName"
    }
}

# Specify the path to your CSV file
$csvFilePath = "C:\computers.csv"

# Read the CSV file
$computerNames = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ComputerName

# Loop through each computer and get Remote Desktop Users
foreach ($computer in $computerNames) {
    $users = Get-RemoteDesktopUsers -computerName $computer
    Write-Host "Users in Remote Desktop Users group on $computer"
    Write-Host $users
    Write-Host "---------------------------"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "within a number of"? Are the user names numerical?

Comment: I aim to add all PC's within an OU and from there then run script to export data of users in said local group on each PC. No most if not all will be letters only.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of the code you are working with that is causing trouble, and the errors or failures that you are encountering.

Comment: Comments are not the right place to provide that. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77915933/edit) your question and update it directly instead.

Comment: thanks for advising TMT and have amended as required.

Comment: `$using:groupname` and you're not piping to Export-Csv

Comment: The updated code you've posted looks good - what's the issue?

Comment: it then displays the following   ```Get-LocalGroupMember : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ComputerName'.
At line:7 char:78
+ ... -LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users" -ComputerName $comput ...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-LocalGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetLocalGroupMemberCommand ```

Comment: Additional to that it then displays no users are showing in the lusrmgr - Remote Desktop Users - Even though i have manually added as number of people.

Answer (score 0):

Command **Get-LocalGroupMember** doesn't have parameter **ComputerName** because it must be executed locally on the computer.

You need to rewrite the script using remote code execution, f.e.:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Remote Desktop Users" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
```